# How to play stream audio in iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, playback

I want to play sounds from an internet server in my own program. But the sample codes Apple supplied concerned about sound play are all open an audio file, and then play it.
I want to know how can I play PCM data from memory, which received from internet continuously. Either OpenAL or AudioQueue is OK.

Comment: I have tried to search few days ago and found the same things you found. I will be watching this question.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a look:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW8